# A bug in Delphi styles with ListView? (Caption disappears in edit mode)

Tags: listview, delphi, styles, vcl

I have a ListView in my application and it works fine with the standard VCL style (Delphi XE8). But with custom styles (from the menu Project/Options and the tab Application/Appearance) I encounter a problem. When I click the selected item or start editing the caption, the caption disappears while the caret just blinks in a grey empty area. The caption reappears fine after leaving edit mode. The problem is only with the custom styles and for ViewStyles vsIcon and vsList .

I googled about it and it seems that no one has encountered such an issue! I tried capturing the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message of the ListView in its window procedure, like the test code below, in order to control the background and font colors of the in-place editor. The colors change but the problem persists: by click or key press in the edit mode, the caption disappears and the grey empty area appears.

And I noticed a strange behavior. When I click immediately on the selected caption following entering edit mode, the caption does not disappear. It disappears when clicking is delayed several seconds after entering the edit mode.

Any help is appreciated.

```
procedure TfrmFirst.LVNewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FLVOldWndProc(Message);

  case Message.Msg of
    WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:

      if Message.LParam = ListView_GetEditControl(ListView1.Handle) then
      begin
        SetBkColor(Message.WParam, RGB(250,250,0));
        Message.Result := CreateSolidBrush(RGB(250,250,0));
      end;
    
  end;
end;
```

[A picture of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j70tq.jpg)

**Update**:
With a painstaking monitoring of windows messages, I found a suspect!: WM_NCHITTEST.

The problem occurs when the mouse pointer remains in the client area of the ListView during the edit mode. By setting the message result to zero for WM_NCHITTEST the problem goes away, but then the mouse click events are not captured in the client area of the ListView. So, I do not know what I should do with this information.

Comment: I can confirm this when `ViewStyle` is either `vsIcon` or `vsList`

Comment: @tom-brunberg. That is right Tom. The same for me. Thank you for noting